# Folderbrowserdialog browsing a remote pc

Tags: c#, folderbrowserdialog, file-browser, filebrowse

I have a question regarding folderbrowser when i browse to a remote computer nothing is showing under that object.

But if i use fileopen and browse to the same location it lists all the folders and files, is there some sort of authenication happening with the fileopen?

If so how can i authenicate so that i can browse with the folderbrowser? 
Once i use the fileopen i can then use the folderbrowser but this is not ideal

```
        FolderBrowserDialog f = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        f.ShowNewFolderButton = false;

        DialogResult ropen = f.ShowDialog();
```